# NSFileManager - Swift - File Browser

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I am new at ios development and I am trying to create an app in swift that will list all the files in the directory (all the files are PDF) and the user to be able to open them.

I have googling this for a the past two days and I am super confused. Can anyone suggest a tutorial or steps I would need to get this to work.

I have started with this in my ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    class func defaultManager()->NSFileManager{

    }

}
```

I just don't know what to do next, very sad I know. I would appreciate any or all help.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 5):

```
let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var array = manager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(_ path: String,
                         error error: NSErrorPointer) -> [AnyObject]?
```

Swift 3.0 version

```
let manager = FileManager.default
let installed_files = try manager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "/Applications/")
```

Comment: you need to pass the directory where your files are stored. which will be probably the documentDirectory or within a subdirectory of it. my code is just a hint but will look like it

Comment: Do i put this code inside my class func defaultManager?

Comment: you can put this anywhere you want. actually your func defaultManager is wrong you dont need it. if you are testing you should put in viewdidLoad. it will be called at least once when your controller appear on screen

Comment: I tried your code, but I am getting an error: `Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: on this line: `var array = manager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(_ path: String, error error: NSErrorPointer) -> [AnyObject]?;`

Comment: yeah you cannot copy paste contentOfDirectory is a method on fileManager. you should read the doc about the nsfileManager to see how to use it. NO NSFileManager is only for internal disk. You need NSURLSESSION for remote request

Comment: Will this get me a list of files from a directoyr from server?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more complete example and updated for Swift 2.

Add your files to a Folder (not a Group) in your project. Then use the following code to get a list of file names.

```
private func getListOfFileNames() -> Array<String> {

    let docsPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath! + "/DirectoryName"
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let docsArray: Array<String>

    do {
        docsArray = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(docsPath)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return docsArray
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am late to answer for you, but the answer may help others. I've found one [library on github](https://github.com/marmelroy/FileBrowser). This is a way to get access very easely to browse files. [At here](https://github.com/marmelroy/FileBrowser#usage) is example:

```
let fileBrowser = FileBrowser()
present(fileBrowser, animated: true, completion: nil)
```